# How to work with each byte in a DDword separately in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, i386

I've a problem with manipulating each byte separately, from an hexadecimal number, for example:

> key:  DD 0xCAEFBABE

from this, I want to take CA and make another DWord like

> 0x CA notCA CA notCA

and work with It, and then pass to the second byte `EF` and do the same thing.

Can you give me some advice or a method to process?

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether you want to do this at compile-time or at run-time.

Comment: I want to do It at run-time, actually I've to make a function that loops through  the key and take each byte and make from It another key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be easy enough:

```
key: dd 0xCAEFBABE
foo: dd 0

mov ah,[key + 3]  ; 0xCA
mov al,ah
not al            ; ax = (0xCA << 8) | not CA
mov [foo],ax      
mov [foo+2],ax    ; foo = 0xCA(not CA)CA(not CA)
```

Comment: Michael, thank you so much, and to print the result, I've just to push the eax into my c++ function ?

Comment: Or, the new key is in foo ?

Comment: The new value is in `foo`. You could store it in `key` if you want to - but it'd be easier to process the remaining bytes of the original key if you leave it intact.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, thank you so much, and how to pass to the other bytes if  I want to put that in a loop, is It right if I make the [key+3] like [key+ the byte I want] ? So, I can put it in a for loop ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In x86 assembly(I use MASM syntax) that's simple. You use a register to fix the address and refer to it:

```
lea esi, key
```

Then you access its content and mask the result (In 'Little Endian Format' of x86 the lowest byte comes first in sequential memory order so this works).

```
mov eax, dword ptr [esi]
and eax, 0FFh
```

Accessing the next DWORD looks like

```
mov eax, dword ptr [esi+1]
and eax, 0FFh
```

Comment: Excuse me, but can I ask know what 0FFh means ? thanks.

Comment: `0FFh` just denotes a hexadecimal value of 255 in MASM syntax. `h` is the suffix for 'hexadecimal' and '0' is the prefix for 'a number follows'. --- My answer is different and probably not fitting, but if you combine both the answers, you will probably get a good result.